# Passing class parameters python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 classes

```
class Robot1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def sayHi(self):
        return "Hi, I am " + self.name


class Robot2:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def sayHello(self):
        return "Hello, I am " + self.name

robot_directory = {1: Robot1(), 2: Robot2()}

def object_creator(robo_id, name):
    robot_object = robot_directory[robo_id]
    return robot_object
```

But I don't know how to pass the variable `name` while instantiating the class on the line `robot_object = robot_directory[robo_id]`. How can I pass the variable?

Comment: This code shouldn't work. As soon as `robot_directory = `is hit, the `Robot1()` calls should fail because of missing arguments `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Also, using dicts that just have sequential numerical keys is an antipattern--use a plain old list for that.

Comment: Yes. It will fail since the argument `name` is not passed. I want to know, how to pass arguments if I try to choose the class from a dictionary. I will come to know about the argument to be passed only when the function `object_creator` is called.

Comment: I'm saying you won't even get that far. `robot_directory = {1: Robot1(), 2: Robot2()}` is invalid, so you can't initialize the dict in this manner, much less choose classes from it. Create a list `robot_directory = []` and use `robot_directory.append(Robot(name))` whenever you want to make a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing already-created instances in the dictionary. Store the class itself instead:

```
# ...
robot_directory = {1: Robot1, 2: Robot2}
def object_creator(robo_id, name):
    robot_class = robot_directory[robo_id]
    # Here, the object is created using the class
    return robot_class(name)
```

Obviously, this requires that all your robot classes have the same `__init__` parameters.

Going further, you might want to look into inheritance and use a common base class for your robots.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try

```
class Robot1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_name(self, name):
        return "Hi, I am " + name


class Robot2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_name(self, name):
        return "Hello, I am " + name


robot_directory = {1: Robot1(), 2: Robot2()}


def object_creator(robo_id, name):
    robot_object = robot_directory[robo_id]
    return robot_object.set_name(name)
```